# Traefik won't add container to backend occasionally on Docker Compose

Tags: traefik

After upgrading to Traefik version 1.7 (docker image: traefik:v1.7
), we see that Traefik sometimes fails to add an automatically restarted container to backend. It will work fine when we restart Traefik again. Here's the error logs from Traefik:

`﻿time="2018-07-27T11:01:56Z" level=warning msg="Unable to find the IP address for the container \"/drone-server\": the server is ignored."
time="2018-07-27T11:01:56Z" level=error msg="undefined backend 'backend-drone-server' for frontend frontend-Host-ci-example-com-0. Skipping frontend frontend-Host-ci-example`

I could not find much information related to such issue. What can we do to fix this issue?